# How do I: PHP ftp_echo

Tags: php, echo

Variation of [my question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61429/ftp-command-one-liner) on Ubuntu.SE:

This is (basically) what I'm doing when I log into a FTP:

```
ftp user:password@server
ftp: user:password@server: Unknown host
ftp> echo HELLO WORLD!
ftp> quit
```

Is it possible to "echo" over ftp in PHP?

```
<?php
$ftp_server = "server";
$ftp_user_name = "user";
$ftp_user_pass = "SuperSecretPassword";
$message = "Hello World!";

// connect
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server); 

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 

// Echo Message
$upload = ftp_echo($conn_id, $message); 

// close the FTP stream 
ftp_close($conn_id); 
?>
```

Maybe I'm an idiot, but all the commands I see are for pushing, pulling or doing stuff locally. Does something else act as 'ftp> echo "Hello World!"' and am I'm looking right at it without realizing it?

Comment: See adam's answer.  The base ftp protocol is available in the api.  That covers the primary use of ftp which is to get and put files.  Anything outside the basic ftp api has to be done with ftp_raw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want [ftp_raw](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-raw.php). You'd use this to put an arbitrary command to your ftp server.

```
<?php
$fp = ftp_connect("ftp.example.com");

/* This is the same as: 
   ftp_login($fp, "joeblow", "secret"); */
ftp_raw($fp, "USER joeblow");
ftp_raw($fp, "PASS secret");
?>
```

Comment: Yup. +1. _Someone_ clearly didn't go through all the FTP functions in the PHP manual. >.<

Comment: I'm trying to put together a long process, my PHP is admittedly weak and I've never been good with "manuals". Don't know if I would have made that connection anyways without an example that just "pops" for me like this does. Thanks :)

Comment: No worries - it's hard to take it all in, I know. That said though, the php manual is very good and the example above is lifted straight from the manual. Good luck with it all!